# Command-line or registry alternatives to Windows Color and Appearance Dialog?

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know of alternatives to the Windows Color and Appearance Dialog?

I would like to set the fonts, colors, and sizes from a .cmd file or from a registry script rather than from the dialog. There are a couple of reasons I want to do this:

1. The dialog is NOT resizable, and if you set the fonts to 125% or 150% in the Display options for Windows globally, many of the controls in the dialog [may] fall off the lower right corner and the dialog can be, in fact, NON FUNCTIONAL!
2. I like to set these options the same on various computers, and it's annoying, time-consuming, and error-prone to set them in a dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in the registry here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Appearance\Schemes

Navigate to this part of the registry and export the data below this level. The themes are stored in a binary format so it isn't the most user friendly so tread very carefully and keep backups!

Comment: Any way to apply these changes without logging off and on again?